# AWS Appflow <-> Salesforce integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, salesforce

I'm trying to setup a workflow to backup Accounts & Contact objects from Salesforce to S3 via AWS Appflow. Perhaps, I'm able to setup the connection and able to backup the files on-demand.

However, for restoration I would like to import the mapping using .csv file and below are sample first 3 lines (using comma-separator source & destination fields).

```
Name, Name
Type, Account Type
AccountNumber, Account Number
```

But Appflow is unable to import as " Couldn't parse rows from the file" - Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was bug on AWS side and it taken up ! Workaround is to do manual mapping instead of external CSV; make sure the source field attributes match with the corresponding objects in Salesforce.